# Self-Contained, service asks for Runtime to be installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Build:

- .net core 3.1, asp.net core 3.1.3.
- Deployment mode: Self-Contained
- Target Runtime Win-x64
- RedyToRun, single file.
- User: win 10 x64, 1903, 18362.788

Its a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1.3 service that runs locally with users. It should not need to have .NET Core runtime installed (as far as I understand it).

It runs smoothly upon installation. User side, my test VMs and my own development environment.

Yet a handful of users have reported that "after not using it for a while" (say a week) they receive the message box saying "To run this application, you must install .net core. would you like to download it now?"

The weird part is: Even if runtime is installed, it keeps asking for it.

It's self-contained, not runtime dependent, this should *not* be needed.

Has anyone else had this issue or ideas?

Comment: I never had this issue. Just a few ideas: does it also occur when not running as a service?  Is there only your application or could the message maybe come from another application? Check whether all necessary assemblies are loaded from your app folder ([see here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7693))

Comment: If it works 'for a while' then it's obviously not the code/deployment that isn't working.  There must be some changes to the users' PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that issue was that the files extracted into the temp directory was partially cleaned up by windows.. causing the application to crash and burn due to missing files. 
Intersting issue that was solved in 3.1.4

Comment: The temp files were probably the json files that also are created during build.  If you see this error outside of a service make sure that all json files from the build are in the exe directory.